# netlify deployment failed during stage "install dependencies"

Tags: deployment, build, netlify

I use auto deploy from github

since yesterday the deployment failed during stage "install depencies"
the log shows following:
....

```
8:52:12 PM: npm WARN     react-reconciler@"^0.20.4" from react-zdog@1.0.11
8:52:12 PM: npm WARN     node_modules/react-zdog
8:52:13 PM: npm ERR! code E404
8:52:13 PM: npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/babel-preset-active-node-syntax/-/babel-preset-active-node-syntax-1.0.1.tgz - Not found
8:52:13 PM: npm ERR! 404
8:52:13 PM: npm ERR! 404  'babel-preset-active-node-syntax@https://registry.npmjs.org/babel-preset-active-node-syntax/-/babel-preset-active-node-syntax-1.0.1.tgz' is not in this registry.
8:52:13 PM: Failed during stage 'Install dependencies': dependency_installation script returned non-zero exit code: 1
8:52:13 PM: npm ERR! 404
8:52:13 PM: npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
8:52:13 PM: npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
8:52:13 PM: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
8:52:13 PM: npm ERR!     /opt/buildhome/.npm/_logs/2023-06-02T18_52_10_286Z-debug-0.log
8:52:13 PM: Error during npm install
8:52:13 PM: Build was terminated: dependency_installation script returned non-zero exit code: 1
8:52:13 PM: Failing build: Failed to install dependencies
```

I have no idea what to do here to make it work again.

images of the error:
https://i.imgur.com/V3U4fvb.png
https://i.imgur.com/0rmhIAQ.png

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check your installation command. If you have a command like

```
npm install packageName
```

then it will not create any problem. But if you have a command like

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```

or

```
npm install --force
```

then it will definitely create problem. Check these carefully.